# Read value from a textbox

Tags: javascript

I have a simple textbox:

```
<input type="text" id="username" /><br />
<input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="Submit()" />
```

The function is defined as:

```
function Submit() {
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   alert("Welcome " + username);
}
```

Why do I get the error below?

> Cannot read property 'value' of null

Comment: Works fine for me: http://jsbin.com/ebijat/1/edit

Comment: The error message means you're not getting the element, you have probably somehow messed up the ID somewhere.

Comment: something isn't quite right here... can you verify that the code you posted is identical to what you have? e.g. you're not calling document.getElementsById() or getElementByID()...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rename your function. `Submit` is likely a reserved word in your browser (though your code works fine in [[image]google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome))

```
<input type="text" id="username" /><br />
<input type="button" id="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="mySubmit()" />
```

```
function mySubmit() {
   var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
   alert("Welcome " + username);
}
```

Failing that, double-check that the code you posted is actually the cause of the error.

Comment: It's not on my [**list**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Reserved_Words) ???

Comment: @adeneo I have no other possible explanation :p

Answer (score 1):

**Internet Explorer** does something very frustrating called "auto globals".

Every element on the page with a **NAME** attribute or an **ID** attribute is automatically assigned as a global object on the page.

You therefore unintentionally have a *namespace collision* because your function and the button are both called "Submit".

Try renaming your button (and/or add a doctype which tells newer versions of IE to stop doing this!)